# How to convert pptx and ppt to pdf and swf

Tags: php, ubuntu, powerpoint, openoffice.org

I am trying to convert pptx and ppt files to swf on a Linux server.

I can convert from pdf to swf, so I have settled on looking for a pptx and ppt to pdf converter.

I have looked at Open Office, but it seems to require an x server for its full version, and OdfConverter does not seem to work right, even to odf.

Is there an API that can do this for me, or does anyone have experience doing this sort of thing well? I found an API that would do this, but instead of charging for the service, they want us to put a link that is unacceptable for our site.

Answer (score 3):

You can run Open Office without an X server (in headless mode) and use the UNO interface from PHP with the [PUNO module](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)